# Alternative SQL Server SMO methods

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, smo

I use SQL Server SMO methods to get SQL Server data such as list of databases.

Is there way to execute above action using ADO.net without sending TSQL parameter to SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You can also inspect the system catalog views, e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.databases
```

to get a list of databases, or

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

to get a list of tables inside the current database.

Read all about the [system catalog views on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx).

But I don't understand what you mean here:

> *Is there way to execute above action using ADO.net without sending TSQL parameter to SQL Server?*

???? what exactly (and why?) do you *not* want to send to ADO.NET or SQL Server?!?!? Please elaborate....

Comment: with way's such as SMO in sql server my program has fewer code line, more secure , and standard.

Comment: @Mehran: SMO is just as much SQL Server specific as querying the SQL Server system catalog views ... I don't see any benefit in that regard